# Find the minimum value of a variable across all possible executions with an LTL formula

Tags: model-checking, promela, spin

Consider the following `Promela` model of two processes that manipulate a shared variable `N`:

```cpp
byte N = 0;

active [2] proctype P(){
    byte temp, i;
    i = 1;
    do
        :: i < 10 ->
            temp = N;
            temp++;
            N = temp;
            i++;
        :: else ->
            break;
    od
}
```

How can I use `LTL formula` to find out the minimum value that the variable `N` can have when both processes are over ?

Answer (score 1):

**In general**, that's not possible. An *LTL formula* expresses a property that must hold over an execution path, whereas by definition of *minimum*, you want to express a property over multiple execution paths. In fact *N* is considered *minimum* only if there is no other *execution trace* in which it has a *smaller value*.

---

**Work-around.** You can, however, find the *minimum value* of `N` by running `Spin` multiple times over an `LTL` formula with an increasing value for `N`, and examine the output to determine the correct answer.

Consider this example:

```cpp
byte N = 0;

short cend = 0;

active [2] proctype P(){
    byte temp, i;
    i = 1;
    do
        :: i < 10 ->
            temp = N;
            temp++;
            N = temp;
            i++;
        :: else ->
            break;
    od

    cend++;
}

ltl p0 { [] ((cend == 2) -> 2 <= N) };
ltl p1 { [] ((cend == 2) -> 3 <= N) };
```

We have two properties:

- `p0` states that it is *globally true* that when both processes terminate the value of `N` is at least `2`. This formula is verified:

  ```
  ~$ spin -a -search -bfs -ltl p0 m.pml 
  ...
  Full statespace search for:
      never claim             + (p0)
      assertion violations    + (if within scope of claim)
      cycle checks            - (disabled by -DSAFETY)
      invalid end states      - (disabled by never claim)

  State-vector 36 byte, depth reached 98, errors: 0
  ...
  ```
- `p1` states that it is *globally true* that when both processes terminate the value of `N` is at least `3`. This formula is **not** verified:

  ```
  ~$ spin -a -search -bfs -ltl p1 m.pml 
  ...
  Full statespace search for:
      never claim             + (p1)
      assertion violations    + (if within scope of claim)
      cycle checks            - (disabled by -DSAFETY)
      invalid end states      - (disabled by never claim)

  State-vector 36 byte, depth reached 95, errors: 1
  ...
  ```

So we know that the minimum value of `N` is equal to `2`.

Let's see the *counter-example*:

```
~$ spin -l -g -p -t m.pml
ltl p0: [] ((! ((cend==2))) || ((2<=N)))
ltl p1: [] ((! ((cend==2))) || ((3<=N)))
starting claim 2
using statement merging
  1:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:7 (state 1) [i = 1]
        P(1):i = 1
  2:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
  3:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:7 (state 1) [i = 1]
        P(0):i = 1
  4:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
  5:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(1):temp = 0
  6:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(1):temp = 1
  7:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(0):temp = 0
  8:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(0):temp = 1
  9:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 1
 10:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(1):i = 2
 11:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 12:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(1):temp = 1
 13:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(1):temp = 2
 14:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 2
 15:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(1):i = 3
 16:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 17:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(1):temp = 2
 18:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(1):temp = 3
 19:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 3
 20:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(1):i = 4
 21:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 22:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(1):temp = 3
 23:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(1):temp = 4
 24:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 4
 25:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(1):i = 5
 26:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 27:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(1):temp = 4
 28:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(1):temp = 5
 29:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 5
 30:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(1):i = 6
 31:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 32:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(1):temp = 5
 33:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(1):temp = 6
 34:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 6
 35:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(1):i = 7
 36:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 37:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(1):temp = 6
 38:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(1):temp = 7
 39:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 7
 40:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(1):i = 8
 41:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 42:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(1):temp = 7
 43:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(1):temp = 8
 44:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 8
 45:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(1):i = 9
 46:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 47:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 1
 48:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(0):i = 2
 49:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 50:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(1):temp = 1
 51:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(1):temp = 2
 52:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(0):temp = 1
 53:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(0):temp = 2
 54:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 2
 55:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(0):i = 3
 56:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 57:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(0):temp = 2
 58:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(0):temp = 3
 59:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 3
 60:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(0):i = 4
 61:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 62:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(0):temp = 3
 63:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(0):temp = 4
 64:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 4
 65:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(0):i = 5
 66:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 67:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(0):temp = 4
 68:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(0):temp = 5
 69:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 5
 70:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(0):i = 6
 71:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 72:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(0):temp = 5
 73:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(0):temp = 6
 74:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 6
 75:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(0):i = 7
 76:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 77:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(0):temp = 6
 78:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(0):temp = 7
 79:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 7
 80:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(0):i = 8
 81:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 82:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(0):temp = 7
 83:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(0):temp = 8
 84:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 8
 85:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(0):i = 9
 86:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:9 (state 2) [((i<10))]
 87:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:10 (state 3)    [temp = N]
        P(0):temp = 8
 88:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:11 (state 4)    [temp = (temp+1)]
        P(0):temp = 9
 89:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 9
 90:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(0):i = 10
 91:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:14 (state 7)    [else]
 92:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:12 (state 5)    [N = temp]
        N = 2
 93:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:13 (state 6)    [i = (i+1)]
        P(1):i = 10
 94:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:14 (state 7)    [else]
 95:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:17 (state 12)   [cend = (cend+1)]
        cend = 1
 96:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:17 (state 12)   [cend = (cend+1)]
        cend = 2
spin: trail ends after 96 steps
#processes: 2
        N = 2
        cend = 2
 96:    proc  1 (P:1) m.pml:18 (state 13) <valid end state>
 96:    proc  0 (P:1) m.pml:18 (state 13) <valid end state>
 96:    proc  - (p1:1) _spin_nvr.tmp:11 (state 6)
2 processes created
```

As you can see, the counter-example corresponds to an execution in which:

- `proc0` stores the value `N = 0` into `temp` and then stops executing any instruction
- `proc1` increments the value of `N` for `8` times
- `proc0` resets the value of `N` back to `1`
- `proc1` copies `N = 1` in `temp` and then stops executing any instruction
- `proc0` increments `N` up to `9` and then terminates
- `proc1` resets the value of `N` back to `2` and then terminates

Comment: Thanks for your comment.